# Class Initialization process in Java

Tags: java, class, initialization

I have two classes :TestClass2 and TestClass3 . TestClass3 extends TestClass2.

```
    public class TestClass2 {
    static int i=10;
    static int k=TestClass3.j+100;
}


public class TestClass3 extends TestClass2{    
    static  int j=20;
}
```

Now when in another class when I print :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(TestClass3.j);
   System.out.println(TestClass2.k);
}
```

I get the result as **20** and **100**

But when I just Print TestClass2.K (something like below)I get the result as 120.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(TestClass2.k);
    }
```

Can someone please explain why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Let's see the following program in java.

```
public class Inheritance {
    static class TestClass2 {
        static int i=10;
        static int k=TestClass3.j+100;

        static
        {
            System.out.println("TestClass2 class : " + k);
            System.out.println("TestClass3 j : " + TestClass3.j);
        }

    }

    static class TestClass3 extends TestClass2{    
        static  int j=20;

        static
        {
            System.out.println("TestClass3 class : " + j);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println(TestClass3.j);
       System.out.println(TestClass2.k);
    }

}
```

The output is similar to :

```
TestClass2 class : 100
TestClass3 j : 0
TestClass3 class : 20
20
100
```

The TestClass2 will be initialized first when the TestClass3 is called which **is inherited by** the TestClass2.

As you can see the console message,  we have an inheritance tree like this:

TestClass2 > TestClass3

So, the static/class variable j of the TestClass3 will be zero as a default value, so the output must be 100.

Comment the first line of code in the main method, then we can see the next result ;

```
TestClass3 class : 20
TestClass2 class : 120
TestClass3 j : 20
120
```

Both class variable k at TestClass 2 and j at TestClass 3 are initialized separately at this case.
So, now we have 120 as an output.

Answer (score 0):

If your Print(int a) method definition is just `System.out.println(a)` then the real result is 20 and 120. Because TestClass3 needs to be initialized before TestClass2. So TestClass3.j is 20. Then TestClass2 initializes k, which is 20 + 100, 120.

In order to help you more, please attach Print() method body too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that the tommybee's answer misses the point.

### Case1:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(TestClass3.j);
    System.out.println(TestClass2.k);
}
```

When you print the TestClass3.j, before the initialization of TestClass3, you get the TestClass2 initialized, because it's the superclass of TestClass3. It means that the k in TestClass2 is initialized earlier than the j in TestClass3, and at that time the j is assigned with zero by default. So you get:

```
k = TestClass3.j + 100 = 0 + 100 = 100;
```

and then back to TestClass3 to initialize the j by 20.

### Case2

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(TestClass2.k);
}
```

In this case, you print the TestClass2.k，and it runs the code in order.

```
static int k=TestClass3.j + 100;
```

You get TestClass3.j, which is initialized to be 20 (don't consider about k at this time, because k is on its way to grow), and then you make the k get 120.